# Firestore functions listCollections() only returning empty array

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my database...
[image]

I have the following code in firebase functions...

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin  = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.getCollections = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const path = admin.firestore().collection('BusinessName').doc('employee');
    const collections = await path.listCollections();

    collections.forEach(collection => {
      console.log('Found subcollection with id:', collection.id);
    });

    return({ collections: collections })

});
```

And the front end code...

```
    let buttonClick = () => {
        let getCollections = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getCollections');
        getCollections().then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
    }
```

There is two subcollections in this path.  This function should return an array with the two test collections seen in the above image.  However, it only returns an empty array.

[image]

and in the functions log...

[image]

I've tired different paths with different database structures, but the return is always an empty array.  There must be something wrong with the node.js function, but it's right from firebase's docs.  What do you think...?

Comment: FYI, I just tried your code and I do get an Array with two elements. Difficult to know what is your problem without more info...

Comment: What happens if you put the code directly in the script tag (i.e not through a button click)? Also, what happens if you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); console.log(res.data.collections.length);`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec On your second comment, given the log output of the Cloud Function, the problem seems to be in there and not in the way the function is invoked, or its results handled. And @ DoubleTri: that means you should also be able to reproduce this problem on a local Node.js script, which might be worth a try since it reduces the factors that might be causing the problem.

Comment: ```JSON.stringify(res) ``` === {"data":{"collections":[]}}.
```res.data.collections.length``` === 0

Comment: ADDITIONAL DATA:  The above situation is happening with the functions emulator.  I just tried the same code in a live version of firebase functions and it runs as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this issue is only occurring while using Emulators, my first suggestion would be to check your Emulator Firestore Database. Is it empty? Did you create the necessary dummy data?

I'm saying this because your database screenshot is a LIVE database, and the Emulator doesn't touch that, it queries the Emulator db, typically located in: http://localhost:4000/firestore

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem!  I'm using a live db, but function emulator with an empty db.  What a stupid oversight.  As tempted as I am to delete this question out of embarrassment, I'll keep it up in case anyone else makes a simulator mistake.  Thanks you.